# Xcode: Multiple Audio Files, Single Button

Tags: ios, audio, uibutton

In Xcode 3.2.5 I would like to play multiple audio files in sequence (50+) from a single UIButton. I've tried several codes but they leak memory. Any suggestions? I'm still learning so please include header and implimentation file codes. My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the interfaces in Audio Queue Services (AudioToolbox/AudioQueue.h). Create one audio queue object for each sound that you want to play. Then specify simultaneous start times for the first audio buffer in each audio queue, using the AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters function.

The following limitations pertain for simultaneous sounds in iPhone OS, depending on the audio data format:

AAC, MP3, and ALAC (Apple Lossless) audio: You may play multiple AAC, MP3, and ALAC format sounds simultaneously; playback of multiple sounds of these formats will require CPU resources for decoding.
Linear PCM and IMA/ADPCM (IMA4 audio): You can play multiple linear PCM or IMA4 format sounds simultaneously without CPU resource concerns.
Taken from [play multiple sounds simultaneously](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks but that's not quite what I had in mind. I want to play a sequence of sounds by pressing a single button.

Answer (score 0):

This is just conceptual, but what about (a) creating an array of sound names you want to play (this can be during runtime), in the proper order, then (b) writing a function where each soundHandler-type object checks to see where it is in the array; if it's not last it constructs a soundPlayer, loads the sound, plays and then calls the next soundHandler in the array. (If it's last it just constructs/loads/plays, and maybe notifies the parent that it's done.) Each soundHandler (I'm just making that up, you'll have to write it) then can dealloc itself when complete.

If you run into latency/loading issues, you could always have each soundHandler call n+2 in the array, and of course then check to see if it's penultimate instead of the end.

Is that more what you had in mind?